# How to get a cookie in +page.js from a fetch reponse?

Tags: javascript, sveltekit, sveltekit-adapter-node

I'm learning sveltekit but struggling to get the value of a cookie from a response after use fetch to get the response. Here is my code which in the +page.svelte and +page.js in src/roots code:

```js
// +page.js
let url = "api/getacookie"

/** @type {import('./$types').PageLoad} */
export const load = async ({ fetch }) => {

    let response = await fetch(url) 
    console.log("see if response has set-cookie header :", response.headers)
 
    let aboutcookie = await response.json()
    // reponse has the cookie in the headers. How to get the cookie value?

    return { aboutcookie }
}
```

How do I get -extract the cookie from the headers - the cookie from the response?

Comment: What is stopping you? You are already logging `response.headers`, that is where the cookie would be stored if there is any.

Comment: H.B Thank you for helping. The question was how do I get the cookie from the response so I can pass it on to the vite server and set it in a hook or something.

Comment: I still fail to what is stopping you, it's a standard [`Headers` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Headers), the API is not that complicated, and there are various libraries for parsing cookies if you do not want to do it yourself.